# Alternative to a mixed design ANOVA for very small groups

Tags: anova, mixed-model, repeated-measures, small-sample

I am currently writing a research proposal for my MSc and am looking to compare two groups of three, over six different time periods. Is there an alternative statistical test that better lends itself to a small sample size?

---

**More about the project:**

The project seeks to compare the effectiveness of two interventions over the course of six time points.

There are two groups.

Each group has three people in.

One group will undertake intervention 1 and the other group will undertake intervention 2.

Three psychometric measures will be used at each time point for each group.The measures give scores for subjective social problem solving change, objective social behaviour change and engagement.

Time point one acts as a baseline.

The other five time points are directly after each session of the intervention (Once weekly for 5 weeks).

Comment: I suggest describing your data in more detail - it will help us answer your question.

Comment: I have done my best to flesh out the problem more, let me know if there is anything else that is needed.

Comment: But I have two intervention groups across 6 time points (2x6), does the presence of two interventions not make it a mixed ANOVA?

Comment: Never mind, I was misunderstanding the terminology - it's a two-way repeated measures ANOVA? I'll update the title.

Comment: That's right yes, sorry that it isn't clearer! I will update the explanation again.